# Why can't I define a Geometry with a Transform in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, pathgeometry

I am trying to create a `ResourceDictionary` á la [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18045882/873565) that contains `StreamGeometries` that have `Transforms` set:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <StreamGeometry x:Name="Chevrons">
        <StreamGeometry.Transform>
            <TranslateTransform X="20" Y="120"/>
        </StreamGeometry.Transform>
        M21.750001,94.749999 L34.000002,117.66218 30.625003,133.62501 17 [...]
    </StreamGeometry>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

However, I get the following error:

> 1: Cannot add content to an object of type "StreamGeometry".

and

> 2: TypeConverter syntax error encountered while processing initialization string '*{PathData}*'. Element attributes are not allowed on objects created via TypeConverter.

So I tried it with a `PathGeometry` and got this error:

> The specified value cannot be assigned to the collection. The following type was expected: "PathFigure".

Is there any way to do apply a transform to a Geometry in XAML code? Or do I just have to do it via code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may write it like this:

```
<PathGeometry x:Key="Chevrons">
    <PathGeometry.Transform>
        <TranslateTransform X="20" Y="120"/>
    </PathGeometry.Transform>
    <PathGeometry.Figures>
        M21.750001,94.749999 L34.000002,117.66218 30.625003,133.62501 ...
    </PathGeometry.Figures>
</PathGeometry>
```

or like this:

```
<PathGeometry x:Key="Chevrons"
    Figures="M21.750001,94.749999 L34.000002,117.66218 30.625003,133.62501 ...">
    <PathGeometry.Transform>
        <TranslateTransform X="20" Y="120"/>
    </PathGeometry.Transform>
</PathGeometry>
```

Comment: What about a `StreamGeometry`? Also, why do I get this behaviour?

Comment: StreamGeometry in XAML may only be written without setting any properties, like `<StreamGeometry>...</StreamGeometry>`. I guess that is because the StreamGeometry instance is directly created by a built-in TypeConverter which converts the path string. That differs from e.g. reading the `Figures` property of a PathGeometry.

Answer (score 3):

About the behavior of `StreamGeometry`, quote from [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.streamgeometry.aspx):

Here:

> A StreamGeometry is a Freezable type. StreamGeometry is light-weight alternative to PathGeometry for creating geometric shapes. Use a StreamGeometry when you need to describe a complex geometry but do not want the overhead of supporting data binding, animation, or modification. Because of its efficiency, the StreamGeometry class is a good choice for describing adorners.

And here:

> A StreamGeometry cannot be serialized if it contains a Transform or any non-stroked or unfilled segments.

Therefore, use the `PathGeomerty`, as advised @Clemens.